# Unix Pattern Matching

Tags: unix, character, match

So I need to do this pattern match and I need to list all files in a folder that have the characters "file" and one more character afterwards.
so I need to type ls -1 *"file"* but im missing what it takes to find all files that have one more character after the phrase "file" such as "file1" "filed" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm, was overthinking it. using ls -1 *"file"? solved my problem!
XP